# Test Connection pyodbc (Python and SSMS)

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to follow some simple steps in this [Microsoft doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) but I can get it to connect.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import pyodbc 
# Some other example server values are
# server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = '029783610657\SQLEXPRESS' 
database = 'LM_Critical_Alerts' 
username = '' 
password = '' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

This is the error message:

PS C:\Users\Nelson.Silva> &

```
C:/Users/Nelson.Silva/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/Nelson.Silva/.../Desktop/conncection test pyobdc.py"
  File "c:....conncection test pyobdc.py", line 7
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password')
                                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 7)
PS C:\Users\Nelson.Silva>
```

Comment: Apparently, I had several steps missing. just followed through [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDXX5evRgQw) and it all worked seamlessly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed your code before posting. In the code block you say the connect line is

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

but in the exception block the line is:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password')
```

The problem is not the connection. Your python code is invalid. Python is telling you that you haven't closed one of your strings: `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 7)` It also gives you a convenient little `^` under where it thinks you haven't closed a string. In the exception block its at the end of the `;PWD='+ password')`.

`';PWD='+ password')` should be `';PWD='+ password)` (notice the lack of ' at the end of `password`)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and tips. However, even doing what you said, it still does not work.